# Why does Flutter/Dart List.from() work while .toList() doesn't

Tags: flutter, dart, nested-lists

I spent a day and half racking my brain trying to figure out how to create a chained selector for my redux store to get IDs from a set of nested objects.  In the docs and all the examples I've read, I know that `Iterable.map()` returns an `Iterable<T>` and requires `.toList()` if you want to treat it as a list.  Eg. as a return type `List<int>`.

What I can't figure out is why my selectors below function while the other does not.  The only thing I can come up with is that it's a nested list that I'm trying to flatten.  I've seen dozens of examples with the same error where JSON was used in a map and the answer was to use `.toList()`.

The only reason I care is because I've work with very large very complex redux stores which required multiple levels of chaining - usually split into sub-selectors.

```
//models
@JsonSerializable()
class Schedule {
  /* the data returned from the API is a little confusing.  Each scheduled item
   * has a primary and secondary task, so each team is usually listed twice for each
   * task.  Once the JSON is consumed and converted into models, I try to get all
   * of the items task IDs so I can get more information about those tasks.
   * Having come from a JSX/JavaScript background learning redux, I'm familiar
   * with that style of chaining.  I've tried to find information about the 
   * "cascade" ( .. ) operator, but information is hard to come by aside form a 
   * brief description.  And didn't make a difference when I tried to use it.
   * The reason each team is listed twice for a schedule under primaryTask and
   * secondaryTask is a schedule items may have 2 teams.  99.999% of the time 
   * it's a single team, however, the odd time a second team will be configured 
   * as only a subset of the team will be assigned to the secondary task.  For
   * the purpose of the "get all task IDs" selector, which team that task is
   * assigned to doesn't matter whatsoever.
   * Example API JSON response:
[
  schedule: {
    teams:[ {
      primaryTask:{
        teamName:String, 
        taskId:Integer
      },//primary task
      secondaryTask:{
        teamName:String, 
        taskId:Integer
      }//secondary task
    } //team
,... ]//teams
  }//schedule
]
   */
  //the map index is either "primaryTask" or "secondaryTask".
  //each "Schedule" item is for a single team.
  final Map<String, Team> teams;

  Schedule({
    required this.teams,
  });

  factory Schedule.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$ScheduleFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ScheduleToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Team {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  
  Team({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  factory Team.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$TeamFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TeamToJson(this);
}

//redux selector that works
List<int> getAllScheduledTeamsTaskIds( store ){
  return List<int>.from( 
    List<List<int>>.from( 
      store.state.schedule
      .map( ( schedule ) => [ 
        schedule.teams['primaryTask'].id as int, 
        schedule.teams['secondaryTask'].id as int ]
      )
    )
    .expand((i)=>i)
  );
}

//The first selector I got to work but I didn't like it.
List<int> getAllScheduledTeamsTaskIdsMergingTwoLists( store ){
  // merge two lists composed of primaryTask IDs and secondaryTask IDs
  return store.state.schedule
  .map( ( schedule ) => schedule.teams['primaryTask'].id as int )
  .toList()
  + 
  store.state.schedule
  .map( ( schedule ) => schedule.teams['secondaryTask'].id as int )
  .toList()
}

  //redux selector that doesn't work
List<int> getAllScheduledTeamsTaskIdsError( store ){
  return store.state.schedule
  .map( ( schedule ) => [ 
    schedule.teams['primaryTask'].id as int, 
    schedule.teams['secondaryTask'].id as int ]
  )
  .toList()
  .expand((ident)=>ident)
  .toList();
  //error message: type '(dynamic) => (dynamic)' is not a subtype of (dynamic) => Iterable(dynamic)
}
```

I've been reading docs and examples and source on GitHub and the behaviour I'm experiencing isn't expected based on what I've read.  However, I can't find an example exactly like mine.  I'm not sure what I'm missing but I'm sure there's some nuance as to why `toList()` isn't working while `List.from()` is.  I've tried `cast()`, `reduce()`, and any method I could find in the docs for `Iterable<T>` that might give me a single `List<int>` from a list of nested objects which I could get into the form of `List<List<int>>`.

Comment: The .toList() works as expected with slight modifications.  Eg. d1's `map() doesn't include the `as int` as I've included in my example.  In my example I'd expect `dynamic<List<int>>` as I've explicitly cast the inner list as `List<int>`.  So given a dynamic<List<int>> following a map, I'd expect a chained `toList()` to convert `dynamic<List<int>>` to `List<List<int>>` which is not the case, and I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Someone deleted the following comment which my above comment is in response to:
Try this: `void main() {
  final d = <dynamic>[1, 3, 5];
  final d1 = d.map((i) => i).toList();
  final d2 = d.map((i) => i).toList();
  final d3 = d.map((i) => i).cast<int>().toList();
  print('runtimeType');
  print('d: ${d.runtimeType}, d1: ${d1.runtimeType}, d2: ${d2.runtimeType}, d3: ${d3.runtimeType}');
  print('value'); 
  print('d: $d, d1: $d1, d2: $d2, d3: $d3');
}`

Comment: `.toList()` will create a new `List` with the same runtime type as the original `List`. `List<E>.from()` will create a new `List` *re-typed* so that all elements are cast to `E`. Your `getAllScheduledTeamsTaskIdsError` function does not specify a type for `store`, so `store` is `dynamic`. The compiler therefore cannot statically determine what the callback for `.expand` should be. All it knows is that the supplied callback is of type `dynamic Function(dynamic)`, but it expects `Iterable<dynamic> Function(dynamic)`. If you want to avoid all of this, you should specify types for your parameters.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, my casting the inner `List` as `List<int>` ultimately has no effect on the `map()` return value which is only returning `dynamic` as a catch all.  Either as `[ i as int ]` or `[ i ] as List<int>` is pretty much pointless.  I did find initial progress with `[ i as int ]` but ultimately got stuck with merging two lists or using the nested `List.from()`.  Thanks!  This satisfies my curiosity.

Comment: btw why don't you simply use `sync` generators? no need for `map`, `expand` etc, more: https://www.educative.io/answers/what-are-generators-in-dart

Comment: I'm not familiar with them.  This is my first project with Flutter/Dart.  I did start reading about them but couldn't make heads or tails of `sync`, `sync*`, `async`, `async*`, `yield`, or `yeild*`.  I was reading about generators briefly yesterday.  I will definitely look more into that.  I know JSX/JavaScript has these features as well but I didn't quite understand what problem they were solving.  The company I worked for shut down in Nov '19 then 2020 happened and there's nothing but a big ol gap in my resume that's only getting bigger.  I'm quite rusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently calling the [`expand`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/expand.html) method on a `dynamic` value causes the error. The result of `store.state.schedule.map(...).toList()` is a `dynamic` (try assigning it to a variable). To prevent the error you can cast `store.state.schedule` to an `Iterable`.

```dart
List<int> getAllScheduledTeamsTaskIdsError( store ){
  return (store.state.schedule as Iterable)
  .map( ( schedule ) => [ 
    schedule.teams['primaryTask'].id as int, 
    schedule.teams['secondaryTask'].id as int ]
  )
  .expand((ident)=>ident)
  .toList();
}
```

Notice that I also removed the first `toList()` call since the `expand` method works on `Iterable` too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  It doesn't clear my confusion since the docs explicitly state: `A list is an Iterable and supports all its methods, including where, map, whereType and toList.`.  I guess store.state.schedule is `dynamic` type which is causing the weirdness.  I will change my code to cast as it's a more elegant, succinct solution than what I came up with.

Re Notice: I did try with the `expand()` directly off the `map()` without the `toList()` as well without results.  It's only with your explicit cast to `Iterable` that it works.  I'm still curious why.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comment above, ultimately I ditched the `map()` and `expand()` for a sync generator as follows.

```
Iterable<int> getAllScheduleTeamTaskIdsWithSync( store ) sync* {
  for ( final team in store.state.schedule ){
    yield team[ 'primaryTask' ].id as int;
    yield team[ 'secondaryTask' ].id as int;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is **exactly** what I meant (I run the same code to test it out, ok I used `final team in ...`)

Comment: Your question gave me insight into how to use `sync*` with `yield`.  Nothing like an innocuous question to resolve clarity to a language feature.